# Set and set builder notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I have this following set notation:

$$
\{n \in \mathbb Z | n = k^2 + l^2\text{ for some integers }k\text{ and }l\}
$$
I don't know if $k$ and $l$ have to be equal for each pair of integers. Or they could be any value?

I would appreciate any help.

My current solution is $\{0,2,8,18,32,50,72,98,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why $k$ and $l$ should be equal, so you're missing quite a few numbers from the set.

Comment: So for k = 0, l can be any value? And after k = 0 is used, can it be reused?

Comment: Yes, for $k=0$, $l$ can be any integer (that's what your definition uses, but only positive makes for an interesting addition), so for both $0=0^2+0^2$ and $1=0^2+1^2$ are members of your set.

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot write $3$ as the sum of two squares. We can only write $3$ as the sum of non negative integers in two ways: $1 + 2$ and $0 + 3$, and neither are the sum of squares.

If you're looking for the elements of that set: https://wstein.org/edu/Fall2001/124/lectures/lecture21/lecture21/node2.html

Comment: The asker never said that $3$ is in the set.  The given set is the set of all $n \in \mathbb N$ for which $n = k^2 + l^2$, where $k, l \in \mathbb Z$.  Since $3$ cannot be written as a sum of two squares, it is not in the set.  Again, the OP makes it perfectly clear that the set excludes 3.

Comment: @amWhy before the edits, the post said "Or it could be any value?" it is singular, $k$ and $l$ is plural, so I assumed (s)he referred to an element of that set. In any case a post full of gramatical errors is not 'perfectly clear'.